# Joomla extension - Custom form with upload function

Tags: forms, upload, webforms, joomla

Does anyone know of a Joomla Form extension with standard Input text fields, textarea fields and Upload field?

I need standard form extension that supports file uploading. Your reply will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of [Chronoforms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508), but there are a ton of options in the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms).